# Problema na hora de calcular

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um exercicio que recebe um valor do raio da esfera, e em seguida faço operações com formulas já propostas pelo exercicio.

Até aí tudo bem, na hora de rodar, roda tranquilo, o problema é que não retorna um valor do volume, em quanto os outros retornam tranquilamente.

```
package pct;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class exer01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        double c, a, v, raio = 0;


        System.out.println("Digite o raio da esfera: ");
        raio = teclado.nextDouble();

        c = 2*3.14*raio;
        a = 3.14*Math.pow(raio, 2);
        v = 3 / 4*3.14*Math.pow(raio, 3);

        System.out.println("O valor do comprimento é: "+c);
        System.out.println("O valor da área é: "+a);
        System.out.println("O valor do volume: "+v);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O calculo não dá o resultado esperado porque ele está a ser feito com constantes inteiras, fazendo que as partes fraccionarias seja perdidas.

Altere para:

```
v = 3d / 4d * 3.14 * Math.pow(raio, 3);
```

A letra `d`, a seguir às constantes, indica que o resultado das operações deve ser considerado como um `double`, de forma a manter as casas decimais.

Answer (score 0):

Você inverteu a fórmula, o 3 é o divisor e não o dividendo. A fórmula correta do volume de uma esfera é `(4 * 3.14 * Math.pow(raio, 3)) / 3`. Além disso, a classe `Math` possui uma constante para PI que você pode utilizar.

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
package pct;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class exer01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        double c, a, v, raio = 0;


        System.out.println("Digite o raio da esfera: ");
        raio = teclado.nextDouble();

        c = 2* Math.PI * raio;
        a = Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2);
        v = (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 3)) / 3;

        System.out.println("O valor do comprimento é: "+c);
        System.out.println("O valor da área é: "+a);
        System.out.println("O valor do volume: "+v);

    }
}
```